# No genera bien mi tabla con un doble while

Tags: php

tengo un detalle con una tabla, en laparte de mi **tbody** de mi tabla con **doble while**, y me genera la tabla con toda la información en una parte de la tabla como en la **imagen 1** con la información correcta excepto el total, pero no me da el formato o estilo de tabla que quiero como en la **imagen 2** , alguien me podria ayudar no se si es la parte donde cierro las etiquetas while o alguna idea de la falla que estoy teniendo???

**Tambien podran ver el codigo completo y modificarlo en:** https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/w2V9fSs2Y1DK

```
     <tbody id="TablaTbodyPersoFalla">
                        <?php
                        include "database/Conexion.php";

                        $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCTROW(falla) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t JOIN f_falla f ON f.Id_falla = t.cust_31 AND t.is_active = 1");

                        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

                            $fecha_inicio = date("2022-10-01 00:00:00");
                            $fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59");
                            $suma1 = $suma2 = $suma3 =  $suma7 = 0;

                            while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {

                                $stmts = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT Id_agente AS agente FROM f_agente WHERE Id_agente NOT IN (1, 2, 3,6)");

                                if ($stmts->rowCount() > 0) {

                                    while ($agente = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
                                        //total
                                        $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(assigned_agent) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t JOIN f_falla f ON f.Id_falla = t.cust_31 WHERE f.falla = ? AND t.assigned_agent = ? AND t.is_active = ?  AND t.date_created BETWEEN ? AND ?");
                                        $stmt1->execute([$fila[0], $agente[0],  1, $fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin]);
                                        $fila1 = $stmt1->fetch();
                                        $suma1 += $fila1[0];
                                        //abierto
                                        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(assigned_agent) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t JOIN f_falla f ON f.Id_falla = t.cust_31 WHERE f.falla = ? AND t.assigned_agent =? AND t.status != ? AND t.is_active = ?  AND t.date_created BETWEEN ? AND ?");
                                        $stmt2->execute([$fila[0], $agente[0], 4, 1, $fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin]);
                                        $fila2 = $stmt2->fetch();
                                        $suma2 += $fila2[0];
                                        //cerrado
                                        $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(assigned_agent) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t JOIN f_falla f ON f.Id_falla = t.cust_31 WHERE f.falla = ?  AND t.assigned_agent = ? AND t.status = ? AND t.is_active = ? AND t.date_created BETWEEN ? AND ? ");
                                        $stmt3->execute([$fila[0], $agente[0], 4, 1, $fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin]);
                                        $fila3 = $stmt3->fetch();
                                        $suma3 += $fila3[0];
                                        //total
                                        $stmt4 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(assigned_agent) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t JOIN f_falla f ON f.Id_falla = t.cust_31 WHERE f.falla = ? AND t.is_active = 1 AND t.date_created BETWEEN ? AND ?");
                                        $stmt4->execute([$fila[0], $fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin]);
                                        $fila4 = $stmt4->fetch();
                                        $suma4 += $fila4[0];
                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="center"><?= $fila[0] ?></td>
                                            <td class="center"><?= $fila4[0] ?></td>
                                            <td class="center"><?= $fila1[0] ?></td>
                                            <td class="center"><?= $fila2[0] ?></td>
                                            <td class="center"><?= $fila3[0] ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                            <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            } ?>


                            <tr>
                                <td class="center table-primary">Σ TOTAL</td>
                                <td class="center table-info"><?= $suma4 ?></td>
                                <td class="center table-warning"><?= $suma1 ?></td>
                                <td class="center table-danger"><?= $suma2 ?></td>
                                <td class="center table-success"><?= $suma3 ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                        }

                        ?>
                    </tbody>
```

**imagen 1**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**imagen 2**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las consultas dentro del while las puedes juntar en una sola usando *agregación condicional*, además que la primera y la tercera las veo idénticas.

Comment: si perdón ya lo corrijo, solo no entiendo lo de while podrías explicarme mejor?